# Error " Can't bind to 'parentData' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from parent component (appcomponent in my case) to child component using @input decorator.

In parent component I am using structural directive ng-tempalate (to render child component html) where I am binding the property created in parent component.

I am getting error "**Can't bind to 'parentData' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.**"

I can't replace ng-template by the selector of child component for sure, as it is guideline to use cxOutletRef of ng-template for rendering child selector.

parent component ts,

```
export class AppComponent {
  public name = "abc";
```

parent component html,

```
 <ng-template [parentData]="name" #tpl cxOutletRef="NotificationAlertContent" cxOutletPos="before" >
 </ng-template>
```

child component ts,

```
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public parentData: any;
```

child component html,

```
<div>{{ parentData }}</div>
```

Any suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: Can you post a link to that "guideline" ?

Comment: @robert, I don't mean Angular guidelines, I was pointing on my project architecture guidelines. As the project is being build on Angular based Spartacus storefront, templates are created to render OOTB or API endpoint driven contents in component.